# Error: Unknown command "migrate\up"

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to install yii2 extension Yii2-user the extension is installed but when I run database migration command :

```
$ php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations"
```

I get this error in composer 'Error: Unknown command "migrate\up"'. is there any error in my command or path. What could be the solution ?

Comment: You should run yii commands inside your web-application root folder. Please, check your path.

Comment: yes i had executed the command in root folder. any other solution?

Comment: Your command and error message are two separate cases. You write here "migrate/up", but show error message with "migrate\up" (backslash), which means you are executing migrate\up instead of first.

Comment: In addition there is no need to write quotes in migrationPath, (it seems you have another error writing @ instead of opening ")